# Is it possible create 2 binaries with different compilers with automake?

Tags: autotools, automake, cross-compiling

I need to build two binaries and each one need to be compiled with different toolchains. Is it possible with automake?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.  Run the build twice, one with one toolchain, and one with the other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was looking for something more automatic. Build one binary with arm toolchain and another binary with a epiphany copro toolchain.

Comment: If you need something automatic it's not hard to write a shell script to do just that.  If you're going to need more toolchains, looking at a [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software) solution might be worthwhile.